# How to upload to cloudinary to a specific folder using the frontend?

Tags: next.js, cloudinary

I have the following code (next.js) that i use to upload images to cloudinary .

- i replaced the cloud name and signature  to cloud_name and my_signature for the purpose of this post .

api :

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import cloudinary from "cloudinary"

const cloud = cloudinary.v2

export default async function controller(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const timestamp = Math.round((new Date).getTime() / 1000);
        const signature = cloud.utils.api_sign_request(
            { timestamp: timestamp, },
            process.env.API_SECRET as unknown as string
        );
        const api_key = process.env.API_KEY
        res.status(200).json({ signature, timestamp, api_key });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(`Error==>${error}`);
    }
}
```

calling the api :

```
export const getCloudinarySignature = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get("/api/cloudnarysignature")
    return data.data
}
```

frontend :

```
import * as api from '@/helpers/api'
import axios from 'axios';

const url = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/auto/upload"
    const { signature, timestamp, api_key } = await api.getCloudinarySignature()

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', imageData[0]);
    formData.append('signature', signature);
    formData.append('timestamp', timestamp);
    formData.append('api_key', api_key);

    const response = await axios.post(url, formData);
```

this works fine when uploading images to cloudinary , but they get uploaded to the root there , i created a folder 'store' in cloudinary and added the following code to the frontend :

```
formData.append('folder', 'store');
```

but i get this error  :

> Invalid Signature my_signature . String to sign -
> 'folder=store&timestamp=1687379533'.

Comment: The upload action requires the signature parameter, and you may check this [reference for more details on how to generate it](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010327340/comments/360002681559)

Comment: thank you , i needed to add the folder when signing the request , works fine now